# Wordpress Sticky Posts AFTER first post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, posts, sticky

I've been trying to make a single sticky post display on the second (or third etc) position instead of the default which is the first.

I have been playing with the loop for hours but I always run into problems.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
  <!-- Wordpress Main Loop Start -->
  <?php  query_posts(array("post__not_in" =>get_option("sticky_posts"))); ?>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : $loop_count = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $loop_count++; ?>
  <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="byline postinfo">by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></div>
    <div class="postdate postinfo"><?php the_time('l F d, Y'); ?></div>
    <div class="commentscounter postinfo"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number('0', '1', '%'); ?></a></div>
    <?php
      if ($loop_count == 2) : 
      $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' ); 
      query_posts( 'p=' . $sticky[0] );
      wp_reset_query();
      else:
      the_excerpt('Read More...'); 
      endif;
    ?>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('No posts were found. Sorry!'); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="navi">
    <div class="right">
      <?php previous_posts_link('Previous'); ?> / <?php next_posts_link('Next'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Wordpress Main Loop End -->
```

What I have done is this:

1. I used query_posts() to filter out all sticky posts from the loop.
2. Used the loop to get the posts and a counter which increments everytime a post is fetched.
3. On the div which displays the fetched post, I added an if statement which checks if the counter is a specific number and if it is, it rewrites the query_posts and gets the sticky one. If not, it displays the fetched post.
4. I then reset the query and the loop continues as it should (almost).

The problem is, after the count reaches the value I want, the loop instead of continuing from the last post, it start from the beginning.

If I remove the wp_reset_query() function, the loop just stops when the sticky post is found.

If I try to rewrite the query to include all posts, I get infinite looping because I'm already inside the loop.

I don't want to break the loop in two or three so if anyone can help fix this using one loop, that would be great!

Comment: try to load it with `$post = get_post($post_id)`. similar to this i answered here: [question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281664/2-query-in-an-array-using-my-code/)